# Restoring a drive image

Tags: disk, restore

It is my first time trying to restore a driver image, I am following the instruction on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DriveImaging. I am booting from a USB, changing the mode of the /dev/sda* to 777 (sudo chmod 777 sda*), and then execute

```
bzcat /media/ubuntu/UUIDofMyDisk/Ubuntu1604_092016.bz2 | dd of=/dev/sda
```

After some 10 hours, the system freezes and when I power cycle it, it takes me to (initframe) black screen.

Am I doing anything wrong here? How restoring image works?

Comment: Why do you `chmod 777 sda*`? It makes no sense, and it's not in the howto.

Comment: Without using chmod 777 sda*, I get permission denied message, that is why I used it

Comment: Then use the `sudo` command. 777 permissions should never, EVER be used, as it allows full access from ANY user to ANY file: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions